# problems with permission "ACCESS" denied on android

Tags: android, permissions

I was trying to extract/unzip ".zip" in my third generation motorola but every time I tried to extract it I get a permission denied (EACCES) message . I do not understand anything about codes and command but still I would like to know a simple way to solve the problem.

To be more accurate about this problem I get this message:

> "(/sdcard / download / wadanohara_103/data/picture/i-miyura4.zxy: open failed: EACCES (permission denied)). "

wadanohara_103 which is the name of the file I wanted to extract.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add file permissions in your manifest file

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```